# How to use variables in bean template

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, hook, drupal-modules

I have a problem with drupal `_preprocess_block(&$variables)` with bean template.
I have module:

```
    function kcc_related_releases_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  // select Bean Blocks and ignore other Blocks
  if (!empty($variables['block']->module) && isset($variables['elements']['bean'])) {
    $bean_array      = $variables['elements']['bean'];
    $child_key_array = element_children($bean_array);
    if(isset($child_key_array)&&!empty($child_key_array)) {
      $bean = $bean_array[$child_key_array[0]];
      if(!empty($bean['#bundle'])&&$bean['#bundle']=='related_press_releases_block') {
        $bean_entity = $bean['#entity'];
        $bean = bean_load($bean_entity->bid);
        $tax_terms = $bean->field_tax_term;
        $related_array = array();
        foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
          $name = $tax_term[0]['taxonomy_term']->name;
          $tid = $tax_term[0]['tid'];
          $tax_term_links[] = theme('tax_term_link',
            array(
              'name' => $name,
              'tid' => $tid,
            ));
          // Get related content.
          $query = db_select('node', 'n');
          $query->join('field_data_field_tax_term', 'fc', 'n.nid = fc.entity_id');
          $query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'uid'))
                ->condition('fc.field_tax_term_tid', $tid)
                ->condition('n.status', 1)
                ->range(0,5);
          $result = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('nid');
          if ($result) {
            $related_array = array_merge($related_array, $result);
          }
        }
        // Tags rendered array.
        $variables['tax_term_links'] = implode(', ', $tax_term_links);
        // Related rendered array.
        foreach ($related_array as $key => $related) {
          $related_links_array[$key]['title'] = l($related->title, url('node/' . $related->nid));
        }
        if (isset($related_links_array) && !empty($related_links_array)) {
          $variables['related_terms'] = $related_links_array;
        }
        else {
          $variables['related_terms'] = NULL;
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And template:

```
if (!empty($related_terms)): ?>
  <h4 class="related-title"><?php print render($title); ?></h4>
  <div class="related">
    <?php foreach($related_terms as $rel_item): ?>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="title"><?php print render($rel_item['title']); ?></div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but it's not work, in template when i use `print_r($variables);` I can find $related_terms
please help me

Comment: I know it's not very clean but you can move your code to template file directly. And why don't you use views module? It's much easier than writing your custom queries...

Comment: After couple checks and searches I found this hook `function HOOK_process_entity(&$variables) {` and this solved my problem after than in my template variables added corectly. Hope it will help someone

Comment: Cool. You should answer your question now and mark as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple checks and searches I found this hook function `HOOK_process_entity(&$variables) {` and this solved my problem after than in my template variables added corectly. Hope it will help someone